Is there a function for sample selection based on conditions?
I am looking for an algorithm and its implementation in R for sample selection. I have a data.frame with i objects, and each object has j unique features. In parallel, I have > 100 samples k that can have three different values (0, 1, 2) for each feature.
My goal is to determine a minimum number of samples so that I have at least each value three times for each object (not for each feature). Can you help me?
I have created a data.frame as an example that can easily be scaled down:
set.seed(1234)

i = 250 #objects
j = 12 #features
k = 105 #samples
values = c(0, 1, 2)

dat <- data.frame("object" = rep(1:i, each = j)) |> mutate(features = paste(object, 1:j, sep = "_"))
dat <- cbind(dat, sapply(X = paste0("sample", 1:k), FUN = function(x) {sample(x = values, size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)}, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE))

Thank you!

You are essentially dealing with a sampling optimization problem. I would approach this this way: 1) Iteratively select samples and check whether the conditions are met for each object. 2) Stop when all objects have each value at least three times. Here is a small example:
set.seed(1234)

i <- 5 
j <- 2  
k <- 10  
values <- c(0, 1, 2)

dat <- data.frame("object" = rep(1:i, each = j))
dat$features <- paste(dat$object, 1:j, sep = "_")
dat <- cbind(dat, sapply(X = paste0("sample", 1:k), FUN = function(x) {
  sample(x = values, size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)
}, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE))

check_values <- function(sub_data) {
  all(sapply(unique(sub_data$object), function(obj) {
    obj_data <- sub_data[sub_data$object == obj, ]
    all(sapply(values, function(val) sum(obj_data == val) >= 3))
  }))
}

selected_samples <- c()
for (s in colnames(dat)[-c(1, 2)]) {
  selected_samples <- c(selected_samples, s)
  sub_data <- dat[, c("object", "features", selected_samples)]
  print(sub_data)
  if (check_values(sub_data)) {
    break
  }
}

print(selected_samples)
length(selected_samples)  


which gives, the samples:
   object features sample1
1       1      1_1       1
2       1      1_2       1
3       2      2_1       0
4       2      2_2       2
5       3      3_1       0
6       3      3_2       0
7       4      4_1       1
8       4      4_2       1
9       5      5_1       2
10      5      5_2       1
   object features sample1 sample2
1       1      1_1       1       1
2       1      1_2       1       1
3       2      2_1       0       2
4       2      2_2       2       1
5       3      3_1       0       1
6       3      3_2       0       1
7       4      4_1       1       1
8       4      4_2       1       0
9       5      5_1       2       2
10      5      5_2       1       2
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3
1       1      1_1       1       1       2
2       1      1_2       1       1       0
3       2      2_1       0       2       1
4       2      2_2       2       1       0
5       3      3_1       0       1       1
6       3      3_2       0       1       1
7       4      4_1       1       1       2
8       4      4_2       1       0       2
9       5      5_1       2       2       2
10      5      5_2       1       2       2
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1       1      1_1       1       1       2       0
2       1      1_2       1       1       0       2
3       2      2_1       0       2       1       1
4       2      2_2       2       1       0       1
5       3      3_1       0       1       1       2
6       3      3_2       0       1       1       1
7       4      4_1       1       1       2       0
8       4      4_2       1       0       2       2
9       5      5_1       2       2       2       1
10      5      5_2       1       2       2       0
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
1       1      1_1       1       1       2       0       1
2       1      1_2       1       1       0       2       2
3       2      2_1       0       2       1       1       1
4       2      2_2       2       1       0       1       0
5       3      3_1       0       1       1       2       0
6       3      3_2       0       1       1       1       0
7       4      4_1       1       1       2       0       0
8       4      4_2       1       0       2       2       1
9       5      5_1       2       2       2       1       0
10      5      5_2       1       2       2       0       2
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6
1       1      1_1       1       1       2       0       1       2
2       1      1_2       1       1       0       2       2       1
3       2      2_1       0       2       1       1       1       2
4       2      2_2       2       1       0       1       0       1
5       3      3_1       0       1       1       2       0       2
6       3      3_2       0       1       1       1       0       0
7       4      4_1       1       1       2       0       0       2
8       4      4_2       1       0       2       2       1       1
9       5      5_1       2       2       2       1       0       0
10      5      5_2       1       2       2       0       2       1
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 sample7
1       1      1_1       1       1       2       0       1       2       2
2       1      1_2       1       1       0       2       2       1       1
3       2      2_1       0       2       1       1       1       2       0
4       2      2_2       2       1       0       1       0       1       0
5       3      3_1       0       1       1       2       0       2       2
6       3      3_2       0       1       1       1       0       0       2
7       4      4_1       1       1       2       0       0       2       1
8       4      4_2       1       0       2       2       1       1       0
9       5      5_1       2       2       2       1       0       0       1
10      5      5_2       1       2       2       0       2       1       2
   object features sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 sample7 sample8
1       1      1_1       1       1       2       0       1       2       2       1
2       1      1_2       1       1       0       2       2       1       1       0
3       2      2_1       0       2       1       1       1       2       0       2
4       2      2_2       2       1       0       1       0       1       0       2
5       3      3_1       0       1       1       2       0       2       2       0
6       3      3_2       0       1       1       1       0       0       2       2
7       4      4_1       1       1       2       0       0       2       1       1
8       4      4_2       1       0       2       2       1       1       0       2
9       5      5_1       2       2       2       1       0       0       1       0
10      5      5_2       1       2       2       0       2       1       2       2

and the number of needed samples:
print(selected_samples)
[1] "sample1" "sample2" "sample3" "sample4" "sample5" "sample6" "sample7" "sample8"
> length(selected_samples)  
[1] 8

